# How to change shutdown script timeout?

Tags: scripts, shutdown, init.d

I have a script running at shutdown of my server, it was added to rc.d scripts with

```
update-rc.d local.shutdown stop 20 0 1 6 .
```

The problem is that this script takes a few minutes to complete it's operations, but the system terminates earlier.

Is there a config value to set, that will extend timeout given to shutdown scripts?

I was testing how long will it take to kill a long running shutdown script.

I have created a very simple infinite loop with:

```sh
while true; do
  time >> /root/watch.txt;
  sleep 1;
done;
```

that script logged about 2 minutes of execution before it was killed.

Answer (score 0):

I spent longer than intended on that one. My test script that takes two minutes to execute (way beyond my normal restart procedure) is able stall the shutdown and to write data on exit without any problems. Also, theoretically speaking, there *should* be no problem with your setup. Scripts are run sequentially, your script is at the beginning of the sequence in rc0.d, it should run as expected.

The only thing I can think of is that your script exits before a process called from the script has finished. You should run your setup with a test script. And you should check your script (or post it here). Pozdrawiam!

Comment: I have extended my question with a sample test script and it's results.